# Re-assign/declare a const variable in a JavaScript for-loop and save it more than one time with different values?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, constants, redeclaration

I know that we can't re-assign or redeclare a const variable in JavaScript as it's constant. but what about that code ?!

```
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
    myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);
```

as we can see in the previous code the `newElement` **const variable**  is being redeclared when the loop iterate. I know that it's ok if we re-assigned a property of a `const` like the `textContent` but how could we **redeclare** it ?!

I tried to put the declaration of the `const` in the global Scope like this :

```
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');
const newElement = document.createElement('p');
for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
    myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);
```

and I got a different output and what was changing is only the `textContent` of the same paragraph as you can see if you run the code in the console.

I hope that anyone could help and tell me why that's happening (how the `const` variable is redeclared in the loop and why it's not working in the global scope?)

And how the same variable (`newElement`) is being saved in the `myCustomDiv` more than one time with different values?

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite sure what you are trying to do, But I'll try to tell you why is doing what it does.

### First for loop

```js
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
    myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);
```

First lets remember that const and let have a block scope, which means that each time before you enter again to the loop the garbage collector  comes and remove whatever thing is not going to be need it any mow, so  each time you enter inside the loop you are creating a new constant. which means that every you enter the loop a new constant is been created. as you are trying to save a collection of `p` inside a `div` use an array.

```js
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');
const newElement = [];

for (let i = 200; --i;) {
    const aux = document.createElement('p');
    aux.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
    newElement.push(aux);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This variable gets created at each iteration of the loop, and also gets destroyed once the iteration is over.

in simple words, it is because of **the scope** of the variable. The lifetime of this variable is only one iteration.